# I need to iterate over text file and print specific text starting from and end fulfilling condition in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

example txt file :

```
vrf X.x.X
hello
!
how are you
!
vrf y.y.y.
hi
!
```

I want to run through above provided text and print the output starting from matching string "`vrf`" till matching string "`!`".
As per above text , I should get output as

```
vrf X.x.X
hello
vrf y.y.y.
hi
```

Comment: what did you try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using [***re.findall()***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) function:

```
import re

with open('lines.txt', 'r') as fh:
    result = re.findall(r'vrf[^!]+(?=!)', fh.read(), re.M)

print(''.join(result))
```

The output:

```
vrf X.x.X
hello
vrf y.y.y.
hi
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, Got it actually what i am trying to open a file and search the specific lines starting from condition and end also with condition..As mentioned earlier...difference is here ,we are assigned the text to string S ...I tried to readline from file and get the desired output..but not successfull!!!